# NMEA sentences are not complete

Tags: android, gps, location, nmea

I am working on android application and i need to get the user's longitude and latitude just by GPS not the network provider. I am using **NMEA** for this purpose.I am receiving few parameters correct as they should be but the others are not. I am receiving in response following sentences.

$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66

$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53

$GPGSV,3,1,09,03,47,205,,07,18,267,,08,09,157,,09,31,316,*75

$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C

I can get ***accuracy*** and ***satellites in use*** from GPGGA from the GPGGA sentence but **GPRMC** and **GPGGA** have nothing. How can I get **longitude** and **latitude**? any help would be appreciated, thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Stand up and move outside of your office. You don't have receivement inside a building. Your NMEA messages show that the GPS chip is running, that GPRMC are enabled but it is not possible to get a valid coodinate. "V" in RMC stands for invalid.

Comment: I know about that "V" thing but last week its was working fine on the same device same location but now its not. I tried it by changing locations too but its still returning me "V". I am using Huawei Device  model : **HWY625-U**